# PHP Efficient way to Convert String of Binary into Binary

Tags: php, algorithm, binary, performance, huffman-code

here is the skinny (scroll down to see the problem): I am doing Huffman Encoding to compress a file using PHP (for a project).  I have made the map, and made everything into a string like so:

```
00101010001100001110011101001101111011111011
```

Now, I need to convert that into an actual binary string, in its current state, it is only a string of 1s and 0s.

Here is **the problem**:

The string of 1s and 0s is 17,747,595 characters long, and it is really slowing down at around 550,000

This is the code I have:

```
<?php

$i=0
$len = strlen($binaryString);

while ($i < $len){
    $section = substr($binaryString,$i,$i+8);
    $out .= chr(bindec($section));
    $i=$i+8;
}

?>
```

How can I make this efficient enough to run the 17 million character string?

Thanks very much for any support!

Comment: Did you take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382738/convert-string-to-binary-then-back-again-using-php

Comment: Yes, base_convert won't accept it because it is too long :P

Comment: Don't write it to a variable in whole, but to some file cache after X bytes. That way, not the whole string is loaded on each iteration to append the next few bytes.

Comment: Yes, the original file being encoded is 4MB, and then broken out via Huffman to the 17m… I know there has to be an efficient way of doing this, I just dont know what it is lol.

Comment: @feeela, I actually am, I just didn't want to clutter the code with that :) It writes at $i % 2000

Comment: can't you convert it to decimal or hex first then do what you need to and then convert it back to binary? Also what are you trying to do with the binary string?

Comment: Normally PHP should run the garbage collector to unset not used data. I would try to use a `unset( $out );` before the end of the loop-block and see if that matters. Or use some `fopen` function to read in X bytes of the input, perform your actions and write to another file. There should be only X bytes of memory used on each iteration.

Comment: why didnt you try to make bit stream instead of bit string? i mean just use 8 bit of the bye from the begining. it s because of locality of reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to loop you can use `gmp` with `pack`

```
$file = "binary.txt";
$string = file_get_contents($file);
$start = microtime(true);

// Convert the string
$string = simpleConvert($string);
//echo $string ;

var_dump(number_format(filesize($file),2),microtime(true)- $start);

function simpleConvert($string) {
    return pack('H*',gmp_strval(gmp_init($string, 2), 16));
}
```

**Output**

```
string '25,648,639.00' (length=13) <---- Length Grater than 17,747,595
float 1.0633520126343  <---------------- Total Conversion Time
```

**Links**

- [Original Dictionary File  (349,900 words) 3,131KB](http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~foster/dictionary.txt)
- [Binary Version  25,048 KB](http://bayfiles.com/file/qBMJ/2g700N/binary.txt)

**Note Solution requires [GMP Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php)**

Comment: Wow! I like that approach, but I seem to be getting a "Segmentation fault" upon initializing GMP in gmp_init($string, 2); any ideas what that is about? (Yes, I have GMP installed :)

Comment: What version of PHP & GMP  ?

Comment: Ahh… I was running it on  PHP/5.2.10 GD/4.1.4, but I moved it to my server with PHP/5.4.7 GMP/4.3.2 and it works like a charm :) Well done! Thanks @Baba