# Comparing Unicode Characters in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, unicode, utf-8

I am unable to compare two unicode characters that to my mind should be exactly the same. I suspect that somehow they are encoded differently, but don't know how to change them to the same encoding.

The characters I want to compare are from the Myanmar Unicode block. I'm running wordpress on php 5 and am trying to make a custom plugin to handle Myanmar Unicode. All my files are encoded in UTF-8, but I don't know what wordpress does.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
function myFunction( $inputText ) {
    $outputText = '';
    $inputTextArray = str_split($inputText);
    foreach($inputTextArray as $char) {
        if ($char == "က") // U+1000, a character from the Myanmar Unicode block 
            $outputText .= $char;
    }
    return $outputText;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'myFunction');
```

At this stage in working things out, the function is supposed to only return က where it appears in the content. However, it never returns anything but empty strings, even when က is clearly present in the post content. If I change the character to any latin characters, the function works as expected.

So, my question is, how do I encode these characters (either `$char` or `"က"`) so that when `$char` contains this character, they compare equal.

Comment: Please can you add
$value = unpack('H*', $inputText);
echo base_convert($value[1], 16, 2);
echo $value;
And give use the output? That function converts strings to binary btw.

Comment: oops - fixed conversion to binary. It's from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382738/convert-string-to-binary-then-back-again-using-php

Comment: what php version are you using?

Comment: Ok, in the post title, where I put only a single က, it returns `111000011000000010000000Array`.

Comment: Php is 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_split` is not unicode aware. For multibyte characters it'll split the them in single character. Try to use either [multi-byte string functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) or [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) with `/u` switch

```
$inputTextArray = preg_split("//u", $inputText, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/ErFwcy

Using multi-byte function [mb_substr_count](http://php.net/mb_substr_count) you can reduce your code too. Like this,

```
function myFunction( $inputText ) {
    return str_repeat("က", mb_substr_count($inputText, "က"));
}
```

Or using regular expression,

```
preg_match_all("/က/u", $text, $match);
$output = implode("", $match[0]);
```

Comment: Wow, that does it. Thank you so much.

Comment: It may be worth turing on mbstring by default:
http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php

Comment: @Danack no for many reasons but most importantly for the reason of losing byte level functions

Comment: @BenSharon see the update, what you were requiring was much simpler.