# can anyone decode an encoded string?

Tags: php, encoding, decoding

Hello to everyone the following sequence is an encoded string, can anyone decode it?
101100101011011100110110101100111101011100111101110011110010100110110100111011010111110011101001011111100110101111100101111111010101

Comment: If the output is a decimal value, you can use this link to convert it...
http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-decimal-converter

Comment: looks like homework :D

Comment: check this out ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382738/convert-string-to-binary-then-back-again-using-php

Comment: Looks like somebody wants to prove that their homebrew encryption system is unbreakable

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it's encoded, try this site: 
http://binarytranslator.com/

If you convert it to a decimal string you'll get:

```
6438910902763710356
```