# String to binary conversion in PHP

Tags: php, binary

I have the following problem, is it possible to convert a string to a binary in PHP?

The problem is that I don´t really mean conversion as such, what I mean is for example:

String = 101010

convert this variable to binary 0b101010

The user inputs the string in a form, which is sent to the script via GET. And I need to create a binary which looks "exactly like this", not conversion of the actual string to binary value.

Comment: do you only want to add `0b` before the string or what?

Comment: well currently I have a code which looks like this:

$start['2']  = 0b0111111110011100010011011011110;
$start['3']  = 0b0111111110011100100011011011110;

these are binary values and I need to create these given the user enters for example 1010011

Comment: Did you look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382738/convert-string-to-binary-then-back-again-using-php ?

Comment: Please explain more of what you want to convert from, what are the possibilities of string values? Is it only binary numbers?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood you want to convert any string into binary, you can do this with use of [`pack()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) and [`base_convert()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php)

```
$string = $_GET['YOUR_VARIABLE'];
$bin = unpack('H*', $string); // H for Hex string

$start[] = base_convert($bin[1], 16, 2); // Convert hexadecimal to binary and store it to your array
```

Credits of this idea goes to [Francois Deschenes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577300/francois-deschenes)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the [phplover's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791144/string-to-binary-conversion-in-php/31791644#31791644), it seems to me that you don't want to convert the string at all.

Normally the `0b` prefix is used for *binary* literals or to assign to an `int` variable or constant.

While PHP does not have a *binary* type, it's enough to have a binary string or an array which represents that kind of data.

```
$str = '110101';// binary for 53

//or array($str[0], $str[1], ...)
```

The string may be used like this:

```
$int = intval($str, 2);

echo $int; //prints 53

echo decbin($int); //prints 110101

printf('%032b', $int); //prints 00000000000000000000000000110101
```

In conclusion: **leave the string as it is**.

[PHP intval function reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)
[PHP decbin function reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php)