# PHP Convert a string primary key to a number representation

Tags: php

I have this id taken from a table:

"B0AL02087"

How do I convert this alphanumeric id to a intergre number representation? I am expecting "B0AL02087" to something like "2011202087".

I found a way of doing this using an alphabet range with a string split, the index of the letter in the alphabet switches out the letters in the key:

```
$alphabet = range('A', 'Z');
$arr = str_split("B0AL02087");
$arr[0] = array_search($arr[0], $alphabet);
$arr[2] = array_search($arr[2], $alphabet);
$arr[3] = array_search($arr[3], $alphabet);
implode($arr), '0');
```

But this method only works when you specify the index of $arr which means it doesn't work when the format of the id from the table changes, e.g.

"BBAL02087"

Now we have two letters at the start of a string rather than a letter and an intergre like the first one. I could write a bunch of if statements check if each index contains a number. I just wasn't sure if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Does converting it to binary work? It would be a complete numeric representation, and reversible.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382738/convert-string-to-binary-then-back-again-using-php

Comment: in lieu of the void specification for ***the number***, maybe state the purpose so people dont have to shoot darts blindfolded.

Comment: You could use `ord()` to get the ascii integer value of each letter.

Comment: For what purpose do you want to convert this to a number?

Comment: The ultimate solution for this requirement, is to convert number from base 36 to decimal (base 10). this will void collision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really sure what you are trying to achieve, but using the examples you provided, you can simply use :

`str_replace(range('A', 'Z'), range(1, 26), Syour_id)`

B0AL02087 will return: 2011202087

BBAL02087 will return: 2211202087

Comment: You can remove one of the range calls it you want. `str_replace(($range = range('A', 'Z')), array_keys($range), Syour_id);`

Comment: Thought of that but it will replace `A` with `0`, not really handy for numerical representations, eg `A320` and `AAA320` will both have a representation equals to `320`, using the `range (1, 26)`, the representations will be `1320` and `111320` respectively.

Comment: @mrbm there is a little limitation in this solution, suppose the following two inputs: `AAA320` and `A11320` here two different values will return the same id i.e collision is occurred!

Answer (score 0):

As I have regarded in a previous comment, the ultimate way to perform this conversion is to convert from base to base, to **void collision**.

From [**this article**](http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/~ram/cpsc110/inclass/conversions.html) which is talking about converting numbers from base to another, and from the description of converting from any base to decimal base 10. I have implemented solution using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) that convert what it is supposed base 36, *i.e. 0-9 A-Z*, number to base 10 decimal which it could be easily converted to [php](/questions/tagged/php) code:

```
baseStr = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  function baseToDec(val){
    n = val.length;
    b = baseStr.length
    s = 0;
    for (i =0; i < val.length; i++){
      n--;
      s = s + (baseStr.indexOf(val[i])*(Math.pow(b,n))); 
        // The non numerical values, such as E or Q could
       // not be multiplied, so we used its index in the baseStr
    }
    return s;
  }
```

This is a [**jsbin demo**](http://jsbin.com/daxizuhobi/edit?html,console,output) and this [an online service](http://www.unitconversion.org/numbers/base-10-to-base-36-conversion.html) that do such conversation to approve, *in some way*, that code works fine since it gives the same results of the demo.

#### Update

The following is the PHP implementation:

```
<?php
  function baseToDec($val){
    $baseStr = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $n = strlen($val);
    $b = strlen($baseStr);
    $s = 0;
   // var_dump($n);
    for ($i =0; $i < strlen($val); $i++){
      $n--;
      $s = $s + (strpos($baseStr,$val[$i])*($b**$n)); 
        // The non numerical values, such as E or Q could
       // not be multiplied, so we used its index in the $baseStr
    }
    return $s;
  }
  echo baseToDec('A11320');
```

[**ideone**](https://ideone.com/69jwkt) demo.