# saving html file into MySQL using R and show that file using php

Tags: php, mysql, r

following code is written by R language
function : save html file into database

```
html_binary <- paste(readBin("EventChart3.html", what="raw", n=1e6), 
collapse='')
sql<-paste0("INSERT INTO test (`att`) VALUES ('",html_binary,"')")
dbSendQuery(connect,sql)
```

following code is written by PHP language
function : show the html file

```
$sql=sprintf("select * from test where id=37"); 
$result=mysql_query($sql);      
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)  ;
print $row['id']."</br>";
header("content-type:text/html");     
echo $row['att'];
```

table only have two attribute 
1. id : autoincrement  ,int
2. att : save binary file  , BLOB

my php show a lot of binary code, I don't know how to solve it. 
please give me help,thanks all

Comment: Have you tried to search for decoding binary like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382738/convert-string-to-binary-then-back-again-using-php ?

Comment: I did,but i don't need to convert the string.I just want to show the html file,not its code

Comment: What do you mean, you want to show the html file, not the code? Aren't you trying to get the html string you stored in binary back into the browser? I am a bit confused about what you are expecting to see.

Comment: My target is save the whole html file into DB,and show it using PHP. but I don't know how to fix it......maybe I mistake your mean

Comment: I try your suggest . PHP shows number too large

Comment: Why do you have to save it as binary? Why can't you store it in a `LONGTEXT` as a string? Does `r` not have that ability?

Comment: thank you . now I use LONGTEXT type to save, but still have trouble......

Comment: But you don’t want to save binary to it, you want to save the string data to it, basically the contents of the html