# inval return wrong number if the number start with zero

Tags: php

I have a number `00101` when I print out this number (or using it for my purpose) I got `65`, I've tried `intval()` but it also returns `65`. Can anyone explain to me why? And what is the easiest way to get `00101`, or `101`?

Comment: can we see the actual code?

Comment: Because its octal value. Read this https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to binary then back again using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382738/convert-string-to-binary-then-back-again-using-php)

Comment: @Rahul Thanks, so do you know what is the easiest way to get `00101`, or `101` in number?

Comment: Code you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are using an invalid type of number, there is bits type (see the list of types in https://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php)

if you run the following

$a = array(10101, 11100, 11010, 00101);
var_dump($a);

you will see that PHP convert your number to int 65

so maybe you want to use strings?

Answer (score 0):

You will get 101 from string '00101' when passing to intval function. However an integer number does not have start with leading 0; PHP does not get it as decimal number.